# Set permissions on list item for anonymous user through workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, anonymous-authentication

I am facing a problem which I do not find solution.

Here is my scenario:
I have a list associated workflow. This list is accessible to the public (anonymous users)
When the field status of the element has the value "OK", I delete permissions (create, modify) to the user on the element and I add permissions (create, edit) for another user.
When the item of the list is created, the public can see the item, but once the workflow has done its job, the anonymous users can not view the item.

Is it possible to modify the permissions through the workflow so that anonymous users can view the item ?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want the creator of the item to not have permissions on it, and the public (anonymous users) to just view the item.

If this is the case, then you  can use an Impersonation Step in the workflow and add two actions. The first action will be a "Remove List Item Permissions" and the second one will be "Add List Item Permissions". In the first action you will delete the permissions you want for the creator of the item and in the second one you will add the permissions of the public group you want.

If this did not work try to

- go to List Settings
- List Item Permissions
- Grant Access for the public group you want (the same you put in the "Add List Item Permissions" action in the workflow). Then if the public group has granted permissions and there is also in the workflow the "`Add List Item Permissions`" action, they will be able to see the item.

Comment: I use an Impersonation Step in the workflow with 2 actions. One to remove permissions on item and the second  actions with "Add list item permissions" but i doesn't work . Anonymous user can't see list item after workflow job.

in the workflow can you edit permissions on anonymous users (or guests) ?

Comment: Is there any error you are getting in the workflow history list?